# How to grab field value during a MongooseModel.bulkWrite operation?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

#### Context:

I am trying to upsert in bulk an array of data, with an additional computed field: 'status'.
*Status* should be either :
- 'New' for newly inserted docs;
- 'Removed' for docs present in DB, but inexistent in incoming dataset;
- a percentage explaining the evolution for the field *price*, comparing the value in DB to the one in incoming dataset.

#### Implementations:

*data.model.ts*

```js
import { Document, model, Model, models, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import { IPertinentData } from './site.model';

const dataSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  sourceId: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
  reference: { type: String, required: true },
  lastModified: { type: Date, required: true },
  status: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true }
});

export interface IData extends IPertinentData, Document {}

export const Data: Model<IData> = models.Data || model<IData>('Data', dataSchema);
```

*data.service.ts*

```
import { Data, IPertinentData } from '../models';

export class DataService {
    static async test() {
    // await Data.deleteMany({});

    const data = [
      {
        sourceId: 'Y',
        reference: `y0`,
        name: 'y0',
        price: 30
      },
      {
        sourceId: 'Y',
        reference: 'y1',
        name: 'y1',
        price: 30
      }
    ];

    return Data.bulkWrite(
      data.map(function(d) {
          let status = '';
          // @ts-ignore
          console.log('price', this);

          // @ts-ignore
          if (!this.price) status = 'New';
          // @ts-ignore
          else if (this.price !== d.price) {
            // @ts-ignore
            status = (d.price - this.price) / this.price;
          }

          return {
            updateOne: {
              filter: { sourceId: d.sourceId, reference: d.reference },
              update: {
                $set: {
                  // Set percentage value when current price is greater/lower than new price
                  // Set status to nothing when new and current prices match
                  status,
                  name: d.name,
                  price: d.price
                },
                $currentDate: {
                  lastModified: true
                }
              },
              upsert: true
            }
          };
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

... then in my backend controller, i just call it with some route :

```js
try {
   const results = await DataService.test();
   return new HttpResponseOK(results);
} catch (error) {
   return new HttpResponseInternalServerError(error);
}
```

#### Problem:

I've tried lot of implementation syntaxes, but all failed either because of type casting, and unsupported syntax like the $ symbol, and restrictions due to the aggregation...

I feel like the above solution might be closest to a working scenario but i'm missing a way to grab the value of the *price* field **BEFORE** the actual computation of *status* and the replacement with updated value.
Here the value of this is undefined while it is supposed to point to current document.

#### Questions:

1. Am i using correct *Mongoose way* for a bulk update ?
2. if yes, how to get the field value ?

#### Environment:

NodeJS 13.x
Mongoose 5.8.1
MongoDB 4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EUREKA !

Finally found a working syntax, pfeeeew...

```js
...
return Data.bulkWrite(
  data.map(d => ({
    updateOne: {
      filter: { sourceId: d.sourceId, reference: d.reference },
      update: [
        {
          $set: {
            lastModified: Date.now(),
            name: d.name,
            status: {
              $switch: {
                branches: [
                  // Set status to 'New' for newly inserted docs
                  {
                    case: { $eq: [{ $type: '$price' }, 'missing'] },
                    then: 'New'
                  },
                  // Set percentage value when current price is greater/lower than new price
                  {
                    case: { $ne: ['$price', d.price] },
                    then: {
                      $divide: [{ $subtract: [d.price, '$price'] }, '$price']
                    }
                  }
                ],
                // Set status to nothing when new and current prices match
                default: ''
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $set: { price: d.price }
        }
      ],
      upsert: true
    }
  }))
);
...
```

#### Explanations:

Several problems were blocking me :

1. the '$field_value_to_check' instead of this.field with undefined 'this' ...
2. the syntax with $ symbol seems to work only within an aggregation update, using update: [] even if there is only one single $set inside ...
3. the first condition used for the inserted docs in the upsert process needs to check for the existence of the field *price*. Only the syntax with BSON $type worked...

Hope it helps other devs in same scenario.